# Auth on servicestack works locally and on iis7 , but fails on iis6

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, authorization, servicestack

I have

1. implemented a basic servicestack-service
2. decorated it with the [Authenticate(ApplyTo.All)]
3. setup the minimum configuration needed to get Basic Authentication ([see this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization))

The service is protected fine when running locally, and similar on IIS7-server - but when deployed to a IIS6 I can't get access to the service. It keeps asking for username/password - but it won't accept the correct combination.

So far I have tried the following without any luck

1. examined the servers eventlogs for errors (no errors/warnings)
2. changed the customlocation from /api to /api.ashx (no change)
3. changed the username/password to a more complicated combination (no change)
4. implemented a custom credentials auth provider (based on BasicAuthProvider) ( no change)

Can anyone suggest what I can do next ?

Comment: Are you sure you have the question title you intended?